# Java simple Timestamp to Date conversion

Tags: android, unix, date, timestamp

I've been trying to find the answer to this for a while today and there's just so much contradictory information....

What I'd like to do is get a current unix timestamp in android, and then convert it to a format that allows me to getHours() and getMinutes().

I'm currently doing this:

```
int time = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis());
Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(time);
mHour = ts.getHours();
mMinute = ts.getMinutes();
```

But it's not giving me a correct value for hour or minute (it's returning 03:38 for the current East-coast time of 13:33).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works:

```
final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
Date date = cal.getTime();
mHour = date.getHours();
mMinute = date.getMinutes();
```

Comment: Doing this returns a time of 07:00.  Is it just that my device's system time is screwed up?

Comment: OK, got it.  I was storing the timestamp in an int, when it really has to be a Long.  Thanks guys

Comment: date.getHours, date.getMinutes, etc.. are deprecated in Android. Use @mbaird's answer

Answer (score 8):

Just use the Java [Calendar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class.

```
Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();  // This creates a Calendar instance with the current time
mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

Also note that your Android emulator will return times in GMT for the current time.  I advise testing this type of code on a real device.

Answer (score 2):

```
int time = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis());
```

here you should use **long** instead of **int**.

Answer (score 0):

Use T[ime](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html) class form Google it is the best for this kind of job specialy it has good performance not like Calendar.