# Android calendar "dtStart" returns unknown value

Tags: android, calendar

How to get calendar entries date? dtStart returns me unknown value which is not my event entries date.

```
eventUri    = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"); 

Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(eventUri, null, null, null, null);

while(cursor.moveToNext()) {     

    int eventCol = cursor.getColumnIndex("title");
    int dateCol = cursor.getColumnIndex("dtStart");

      System.out.println("Event: " + cursor.getString(eventCol)
          + "; Date of Event: " + cursor.getString(dateCol));

}
```

OUTPUT:

Event: PROJECT MEETING ; Date of event: 1304236800000

Would appreciate if anyone can help. Thank you

***Problem is solved. I need to convert the timestamp to readable Date format

```
Date date = new Date (date);
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat ("E-dd-MMM:HH:mm:ss-yyyy");
dateFormat.format(date);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not unknown time, but UNIX timestamp, conversion is proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661137/java-simple-timestamp-to-date-conversion).