# android - generate random date and time

Tags: java, android, arrays, datetime

to trigger some future events I'm trying to create an algorithm which would do the following:

- generate a certain amount of random dates in format "`yyyy-mm-dd`"
- generate time for each date in format "`hh:mm:ss`" Time should be (24h) between 9 and 22 hours
- Add those items to a String array. 1 complete array entry looks like "`2013-02-25 09:45:23`"

I have no clear ideas how to perform this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Generate random longs in the desired range and convert them to a date with `new Date(long)` and formatting it as you need it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Exact Solution what you need..

```
public class RandomDateTime {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SimpleDateFormat dfDateTime  = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss",Locale.getDefault());
        int year = RandomDateTime.randBetween(1900, 2013);// Here you can set Range of years you need
        int month = RandomDateTime.randBetween(0, 11);
        int hour = RandomDateTime.randBetween(9, 22); //Hours will be displayed in between 9 to 22
        int min = RandomDateTime.randBetween(0, 59);
        int sec = RandomDateTime.randBetween(0, 59);


        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, 1);
        int day = RandomDateTime.randBetween(1, gc.getActualMaximum(gc.DAY_OF_MONTH));

        gc.set(year, month, day, hour, min,sec);

        System.out.println(dfDateTime.format(gc.getTime()));

    }


    public static int randBetween(int start, int end) {
        return start + (int)Math.round(Math.random() * (end - start));
    }
}
```

You can find out more uses of SimpleDateTime at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: the `randBetween` method gives the edge values with only half the probability of the values within the interval.

Answer (score 2):

what you can do is using the random function get the random timestamp, I mean you can get the random long value easily and then convert that timestamp to the date object like this

[Java simple Timestamp to Date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661137/java-simple-timestamp-to-date-conversion)

Answer (score 1):

The idea is very simple. You can use Date(milis) constructor and random number generator, to generate random dates and times. You have to find lower and upper bound and randomly pick a number from between.

Formatting date and time is very simple and you can do this using DateFormat class.