# How to show date manually to user when button is pressed?

Tags: android, android-activity

```
package pratyush.grapudai;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

     public void SubmitOrder(View view) {

        printStandardDate(Date);
    }


    private String printStandardDate(Date date) {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm").format(date);
    }

}
```

Actually I want it to show date when a button is pressed.
Like using a function `public void ButtonPressed(View view) { }`
Is there any other  better possible code?

Comment: What do you mean by _"show date manually"_?

Comment: input and SHow any particular date at random?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14976523/android-generate-random-date-and-time

Comment: actually i need it to show date when i press a particular button i.e Todays date = 24/03/15 ?

Answer (score 0):

You may try one of these alternative ways,

**1. Date() + SimpleDateFormat()**

```
 DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date)); //2014/08/06 15:59:48
```

**2. Calender() + SimpleDateFormat()**

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime())); //2014/08/06 16:00:22
```